# How does ens.domains generate unique NFT images with the ens domain name on it at purchase?

Tags: nft, ens

How does ens.domains generate unique NFT images with the ens domain name on it at purchase?

What I mean is: So when you find and purchase your ens domain on ens.domain, after purchase you're instantly given an NFT avatar that represents your ens. It usually consists of the ens domain name and the ens logo. It's pretty simple as you can see from the samples [here](https://opensea.io/collection/ens) on OpenSea.

So the question is how are they doing this behind the scenes? Are there any javascript libraries that can assist with this kind of custom unique image generation function?